# Can't use "const" and "define" in PHP class

Tags: php

I am pulling my hair out on this one. Pretty new at PHP but this is so basic I just can't figure out where the problem is. Using the code snippet below as an example:

```
class LG_Activity_Processor {
// Activity Types
const STATUS_DRAFT = 'draft';
const STATUS_PUBLISH = 'publish';
...
private $STATUS_FUTURE = 'future';
define ("STATUS_PRIVATE" , 'private');
```

I had originally intended to just use the "const" construct as the variables are fully defined prior to run time and I just think the syntax is prettier than that ugly "define". The problem is while the definition of the **const** gives no errors, whenever I refer to the constant later in the class I get the following error message:

> PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant STATUS_PUBLISH - assumed 'STATUS_PUBLISH'

Huh? Just to be clear, here's the syntax I used to reference the "const":

```
$core_fields ['post_status'] = STATUS_PUBLISH;
```

I even tried:

```
$core_fields ['post_status'] = $this->STATUS_PUBLISH;
```

No love. I then entered a state of despair and eventually tried "define". Same calling syntax but I changed the definition syntax to that as illustrated above for "STATUS_PRIVATE". This made things far worth as I now had a fatal error on the define line that looked like this:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting T_FUNCTION
```

I gave up. I finally just defined the variable as a private variable (as in the example of STATUS_FUTURE) and then referred to it as:

```
$core_fields ['post_status'] = $this->STATUS_PUBLISH;
```

That works just like you'd expect it to but I can't help but feeling I've been cheated out of doing it the right way. Any ideas on how to make my code whole again?

Comment: Don't use define() in classes - `const` is what you need. Use `ClassName::CONST_NAME` outside of a class, and in the same class, just use `self::CONST_NAME`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should do `LG_Activity_Processor::STATUS_DRAFT` when accessing it.

Take a look at the PHP manual, it gives you clear examples.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php

Comment: Or just `self::STATUS_DRAFT` if used within the scope of the class itself.

Comment: @Madmartigan that is only available if you are inside the class. It will work here, but using the full classname will work everywhere.

Comment: I assumed he was working in the scope of the class by seeing the code `$this->STATUS_PUBLISH`

Comment: I am working within the scope of the class itself. I'll try the self:: abbreviation as soon as I've dropped the dog off this morning. I could have sworn I had tried the fully qualified LG_Acitivity_Processor:: but maybe I didn't. In any regard, thanks for the pointer and I'll hopefully close this out in the next hour or so.